# Jquery Datepicker day deactivaion

Tags: jquery

Here is my code and I don't know why it is not working

```
beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
                            dmy = dt.getDay();
                            //console.log($.inArray("6", dayNameId) == -1);
                            if ($.inArray(dmy, dayNameId) == -1) {
                                return [false, "Unavailable"];
                            }
                            else {
                                return [true, "Available"];
                            }

                        },
```

Comment: Neither do I. What is this function supposed to do? How are you using it and how is it not working?

Comment: We don't either if you don't explain what you expect it to do or what it is doing differently. Also we have no idea what `dayNameId` is. Take a few  minutes to help us help you by reading [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I want to disable a certain days in jquery DatePicker  that is stored in a array like dayNameId[2,3,4,5] but when the condition is checked ($.inArray(dmy, dayNameId) == -1) it returns true for all check which is not correct. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

here is an working example:

```
Date.prototype.getWeekDay = function() {
    var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    return weekday[this.getDay()];
}

 var unavailableDates = ["Monday", "Friday"];

function available(date) {
  var dmy = date.weekday();

  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
    return [true, "", "Available"];
  } else {
    return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
  }
}

$('#date').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: available
});
```

Comment: This one is for specific dates but mine is for certain days like sunday or monday.

Comment: Unfortunately, Date object in javascript returns information about Days only in numeric format. The faster thing you can do is to create an array of day weeks and create a function which returns the name based on the number.

Comment: I edit my answer but didn't get to test it, it might help as getWeekDay() declared for an date object.